# Select specif value in the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table "Message_group" like that and AAAA is my profile_id of login.

```
message_group_id | profile_id | group_id

    1            AAAAA      1000
    2            EEEEE      1000
    3            AAAAA      2000
    4            FFFFF      2000
    5            AAAAA      3000
    6            HHHHH      3000
    7            WWWWW      4000
    8            RRRRR      4000
```

I would like a query that gives the result:

```
1 EEEEE 1000
2 FFFFF 2000
3 HHHHH 3000
```

Comment: sorry, I did not get the point of your question. what are you trying to select? I do not understand WHAT your query should return and what you are going to use as selection parameters.

Comment: @sailingthoms: He is searching for `AAAAA` and wants all other rows with the same `group_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table with itself to get the rows with the same `group_id` as the one you are searching for.

```
SELECT b.* FROM Message_group a
JOIN Message_group b ON a.group_id=b.group_id
WHERE a.profile_id = 'AAAAA'
AND b.profile_id != a.profile_id;
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a548/1

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not a homework... So, try the following statement:

```
SELECT x.message_group_id, y.profile_id, y.group_id
FROM Message_group x
  INNER JOIN Message_group y
  ON (x.message_group_id * 2 = y.message_group_id);
```

If it works I'll explain you better. ^^

Comment: My answer should win because of my creativity :) And also my [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b406b0/1) shows it's right (:

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  yourtable.*
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM yourtable WHERE profile_id='AAAAA')
  AND profile_id != 'AAAAA'
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand u correctly, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT login_id 
FROM message_group 
WHERE login_id <> 'AAAAA' AND group_id IN ( SELECT group_id 
                                            FROM message_group 
                                            WHERE login_id='AAAAA')
```

u can try it in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99eee/8).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SET @rowno = 0;
SELECT @rowno:=@rowno+1 `rn`, profile_id, group_id
FROM Message_group
WHERE profile_id = 'EEEEE' AND group_id = '1000'
|| profile_id = 'FFFFF' AND group_id = '2000'
|| profile_id = 'HHHHH' AND group_id = '3000';
```

and the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edf7d/10